# Random Sampling of Pandas data frame (both rows and columns)

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I know how to randomly sample few rows from a pandas data frame. Lets say I had a data frame df, then to get a fraction of rows, I can do :

```
df_sample = df.sample(frac=0.007)
```

However what I need is random rows as above AND also random columns from the above data frame.

Df is currently 56Kx8.5k. If I want say 500x1000 where both 500 and 1000 are randomly sampled how to do this?

I think one approach would be do something like

df.columns to get a list of columns names.

Then do some random sampling of the indices of this list of columns and use that random indices to filter out remaining columns?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just call `sample` twice, with corresponding axis parameters:

```
df.sample(n=500).sample(n=1000, axis=1)
```

For the first one, axis=0 by default. The first sampling samples lines, while the second considers columns.

Comment: cool. didn't know this. just to check will calling twice will make sure we are having the same rows (500) on which we get the sample columns?

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, `df.sample(n=500)` will return a dataframe of 500 rows and 8.5k columns. On that dataframe calling `.sample(n=1000, axis=1)` will return another dataframe, with the 500 rows that have been selected previously and 1000 columns.